# Bad order in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In my little playlist script : http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/popup.html#/radio

The IDS are not correctly ordered : 1,10,11,2,3 ...

My json is here http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/data/radio.json , and my html is :

```
            <div ng-repeat="song in songs.radio track by song.id | orderBy:'song.id*1'" class="list-group-item" id="{{song.id}}" ng-class="{ 'active' : songPlayed_name == song.name }">
            </div>
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your id's are actually strings, not numbers. You would either format your JSON correctly (not wrap numbers in quotes) or just iterate through list and parse those strings as integer values.

```
angular.forEach($scope.songs.radio, function (song) {
  song.id = parseFloat(song.id, 10);
});
```

Comment: I rewrited my json like you said http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/data/radio.json but it's still bad order

Comment: Okey, I see that this is not working, but now I'm guessing, that the problem is that your songs.radio is not an array, it's a object with songs as properties. That might by why it's not working as it should. I'm just guessing here, but I think that's how songs.radio should be declared - as a array

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter

please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/PrALxOJfmtcXUntbPmSz?p=preview

```
<div ng:controller="Main">
      <div ng:repeat="song in songs.radio | toArray | orderBy: 'id'">
        {{song.id}} {{song.title}}

      </div>
```

**JS:**

```
 angular.module('app', ['angular-toArrayFilter'])

    .controller('Main', function Main($scope) {

      $scope.songs = {
        "radio": {
          "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "coucou",
            "title": "\"Coucou, tu veux voir ma bite ?\" l'hymne officiel du MDR !",
            "vote": "7,5"
          },
          "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "kissed",
            "title": "\"I kissed a rat\" - KitschNSniff",
            "vote": "9,5"
          },
          "3": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "rats",
            "title": "\"It's Rats, It's Rats, It's Rat\" - KitschNSniff",
            "vote": "9,5"
          },
          "4": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "merguez",
            "title": "\"Merguez-Partie\" - le tube culte",
            "vote": "8,5"
          },
          "5": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "etchebest",
            "title": "\"Etchebest 1664\" - la pub culte",
            "vote": "8,5"
          },
          "6": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "gitan",
            "title": "\"Gitan Ã©nervÃ©\" - LE SANG DE VOS MORTS !",
            "vote": "7,5"
          },
          "7": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "coral",
            "title": "\"Karl, Koraaal, Koarl, Karol\"",
            "vote": "5,5"
          },
          "8": {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "sax",
            "title": "\"Saxo Guy\" - musique idÃ©ale pour se dÃ©tendre",
            "vote": "6,5"
          },
          "9": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "longtime",
            "title": "\"Tomorow is a long time\" - Bob Dylan",
            "vote": "5,5"
          },
          "10": {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "blackbird",
            "title": "\"Blackbird Song\" - Lee DeWyze",
            "vote": "7,5"
          },
          "11": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "crazy",
            "title": "\"Crazy\" - Ninet Tayeb & the Rose Band",
            "vote": "6,5"
          }
        }
      }

    })
```

Comment: That [first song title](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#auto/en/Coucou%2C%20tu%20veux%20voir%20ma%20bite) surely is... *entertaining*.

Comment: @ sss : i add it to http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/popup.html#/radio , it's working but i have this error : Object.keys called on non-object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at http://www.monde-du-rat.fr/zombieReport/resources/libs/angularjs/toArrayFilter.js:10:21
 . You have not this error in the plnkr, why in my app ?

Comment: @JoDiii in radioCtrl.js please change $scope.songs = []; for $scope.songs = {};

Comment: @try this move $scope.songs = {} to top and change html a bit to <div ng-repeat="song in songs.radio | toArray | orderBy: 'id'" ng-if="songs.radio">

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

- you do not want to sort the items by `song.id` but by `id`
- to sort your items they should be contained in an array rather then an object

I changed both points and this is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CaU5TbFQTm9hVls5S3RG?p=preview